# jquery generated anchors in local html file have filename appended

Tags: jquery, html

I'm a little baffled by why this is happening...

I have the following code saved as a standalone html file on my PC's desktop:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function load() {
                $.getJSON( "http://somedomain.json?&jsonp=?", function(json) {
                  $.each(json.data.children, function(i,item){
                        var iData = item.data;
                        var commentLink = "www.somedomain.com" + iData.permalink;

                        $("<a href='"+commentLink+"'>Comments</a>").appendTo("#content");   
                        $("<br/>").appendTo("#content");

                });
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="load()">
        <div id="content" />    
    </body>
</html>
```

It all works fine, except that the links end up looking like this:

`file:///C:/Users/myname/Desktop/www.somedomain.com/comments/somesubdomain/`

Is this expected behavior for what I am doing, or did I do something wrong?

I am opening the standalone html in firefox FWIW.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is happening because you are not referencing the `http://` in your `commentLink` variable.

The browser then recognizes it as a local file, local to your desktop.

If you change

`var commentLink = "www.somedomain.com" + iData.permalink;`

to

`var commentLink = "http://www.somedomain.com" + iData.permalink;`

I think it should work.

Comment: Ack! What a simple mis-step! :) Apparently I can't accept for 11 more minutes :(

Comment: It is almost always the simplest!! ;-)